# Mysql Updating table With Substring

Tags: mysql

i have table name `master` and column name with `number`

column `number` have `value = A011017`

I want change 5=0 change with 2

i have try with this code

```
update master set number =substr(number,5,1) where number like 'A011%'
```

I want change all rows with 2 in the 5th position

Help me please

Comment: "column Number have value = A011017 I want change 5=0 change with 2"...please explain it clearly.

Comment: maybe `A011017` to `A011217`?

Comment: i mean record number 5 from A011017 is zero (0) i want change  value with 2

Comment: for all records whose start vith `A011` or only for this one?

Comment: All record whose start vith A011

Comment: I want change all rows with 2 in the 5th position

Comment: I suggest you give some examples of values you want to change and the result, including some examples of values you do not want to change. For example, A011017 -> A011217, A011317 -> unchanged, etc.

Comment: I want change all rows with 2 in the 5th position

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
update master 
set number =
concat(substring(number,1,4),"2",substring(number,6))
where number like 'A0110%'
;
```

You can adjust the `where` clause accordingly (not sure whether you want all rows with 0 in the 5th position or just those rows starting with 'A011'). For example, if you want to change all rows with '0' in the 5th position to have '2' in the 5th position then use this:

```
update master 
set number =
concat(substring(number,1,4),"2",substring(number,6))
where substring(number,5,1) = "0"
;
```

...or if you want to change all rows with '2' in the 5th position to have '0' in the 5th position then use this:

```
update master 
set number =
concat(substring(number,1,4),"0",substring(number,6))
where substring(number,5,1) = "2"
;
```

Comment: I want change all rows with 2 in the 5th position

Comment: I want change all rows with 2 in the 5th position